# Improve MongoDB Query performance for large data set

Tags: mongodb, rest, .net-core, indexing, performance-testing

I am quite new to MongoDB and I’ve been assigned to deal with a really large data set (a Collection with over a billion documents) by querying it (Find() operation) with a filter of dates and another value. This is done via a Restful API written in .NET Core which utilizes the MongoDB driver.

First thing I created a Compound Index of the datetime field and the other field but still performance time of queries is poor (it could go beyond minute, but sometimes it is just a couple of seconds, I can't tell the reasons). I don’t know if adding more Indexes would really help so I consider migrating the Collection to a Time-Series collection.

I’d be glad to head everyone’s thoughts and advises plus what would be cheapest way to migrate a large collection such as this to Time-Series collection?

all documents in the collection maintain the same structure of 26 fields (not including _id) with no nested fields (Some of them have an extra field which I consider to delete).

The Index I created is:

```
{
"dateTime" : 1,
"securityId" : 1
}
{
"v" : 2,
"name" : "dateTime_1_securityId_1"
}
```

The query I'm using is done via C# MongoDB driver:

```
var filter = Builders<Quote>.Filter.And(
                Builders<Quote>.Filter.Eq(x => x.SecurityId, int.Parse(assetId, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer)),
                Builders<Quote>.Filter.Gte(x => x.DateTime, from),
                Builders<Quote>.Filter.Lte(x => x.DateTime, to));
            var results = await _myCollection.Find(filter)
                                    .Skip(page * pageSize)
                                    .Limit(pageSize)
                                    .ToListAsync();
```

As you can see I'm paginating the results and I know this can be harming the query performance but this appears so far to be a relatively minor issue.

MongoDB version: 5.0.17, runs as a Standalone on an On-Prem Ubuntu server. Compound Index size is 48.9 GB.

Comment: Just adding indexes does not help, it makes updates, deleting and inserts even slower. You have to create the **right** indexes, i.e. which can be used by your query. Please provide a few sample documents, the indexes you defined, the query you run and ideally also the execution plan. You may consider to deploy a [sharded cluster](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/sharding/).

Comment: I would defienately consider a sharded cluster but right now this is not available. I'll add sample documents and the Index shortly.

Comment: And what is your query? Without a query nobody can help you.

Comment: What do you mean by execution plan? is this the output of explain() method?

Comment: Yes, you get it with `explain()`. However, it looks like you did already the optimum, all condition fields in the query are part of the index. How many documents do you get? Loading thousands of documents from a database simply takes some time, a sharded cluster should improve it though.

Comment: I limit the documents to thousands, say 5K or 10K.

Comment: mmm ... yes you done it right .... maybe other thing you can try are: 1 - play a little bit with index .. so try to create a alone index for the SecurityId and one index for the datetime field asceding / descending .. or try the same as you've done but with datetime descending .. 2 - in mongodb the pagination di a scan of documents .. the best practice (if is possibile) is to use LastId and BeforeID .. something like descibed here https://medium.com/swlh/mongodb-pagination-fast-consistent-ece2a97070f3

Comment: Thanks @federicoscamuzzi. I do consider switching from ordinary pagination to cursor-based pagination like you mentioned, it seems possible with datetime field.